# Why is my django-crontab cronjob not executing?

Tags: python, django, django-crontab

I have a `django-project` with an app called `app` that has a file called `cron.py` with a function called `main_routine()`.

I want the `main_routine()` function to be called every minute.

In my `django-project/django-project/settings.py` I have this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_crontab',
    ...
]

...

CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'app.cron.main_routine')
]
```

My `django-project/app/cron.py` looks like this:

```
from app.models import SomeModel
from django.utils import timezone

def main_routine():
    object = SomeModel.objects.get(name='TestObject1')
    object.updated = timezone.now()
    object.save()
```

Of course I ran : `python3 manage.py crontab add`
And the terminal printed:

```
adding cronjob: (someHash) -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'app.cron.main_routine')
```

To be safe I run: `python3 manage.py crontab show`
And the terminal prints:

```
Currently active jobs in crontab:
someHash -> ('*/1 * * * *', 'app.cron.main_routine')
```

To check if evrything works I run: `python3 manage.py crontab run someHash`

Then I take a look at the admin page and see that `TestObject1` has an `updated` datetime of just now. (so far everything seems to be gooing smoothly)

**The main issue: No matter how long I wait the job will not be executed automatically.**

What am I doing wrong?

some Background info:

- I am running this inside an Ubuntu Docker Conatiner on a VPS with nothing else on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I still do not know why `crontab` is not working.

However I found a way around this issue.

You can use the *python advanced scheduler* aka. `apscheduler`, to substitute `crontab`.

The idea is to write a module that has your desired functionality in it, and wire it into on of your apps `AppConfig` in its `apps.py` file.

There is a great walkthrough in [this article](https://medium.com/@kevin.michael.horan/scheduling-tasks-in-django-with-the-advanced-python-scheduler-663f17e868e6).

Answer (score 0):

> Can't comment cause i'm new

This exact same thing was happening to me until I manually ran it like you did (with the hash). Turns out I had a bug in my code so when it got to it, crontab automatically cancelled it since it was producing an error!

I've set up a 5 minute timer to validate that the job ran successfully and it did. I have the exact same setup as you do (+ some factories and api requests)

Comment: The project is now way bigger and I switched to `django-apscheduler`. It is way more advanced and also gives you error logs if something goes wrong.